# Customizing string format in a Caliburn.Micro convention bound TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, caliburn.micro

I have a WPF `TextBox` that is bound to a view-model number property `Distance` through *Caliburn.Micro* naming conventions. I want to be able to customize the `TextBox` string format while preserving the convention binding that *Caliburn.Micro* has set up. How should I do that?

From my *View Model*:

```
public double Distance
{
    get { return _distance; }
    set
    {
        _distance = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Distance);
    }
}
```

From my *View*:

```
<TextBox x:Name="Distance"/>
```

When the `Distance` is non-zero, I want to display the number with a fixed set of decimals, and when the `Distance` is zero I want the text box to be empty.

Using explicit binding I can bind the `TextBox.Text` property to `Distance`, and then I can set the `StringFormat` simultaneously:

```
<TextBox x:Name="Distance" Text="{Binding Distance, StringFormat=0.000;;#}"/>
```

However, the explicit `Text` binding would then short-circuit the *Caliburn.Micro* naming convention binding. Is it possible to customize the string format without simultaneously having to set the binding path of the `TextBox.Text` property, so that I can solely rely on *Caliburn.Micro* to handle the `Distance`-to-`TextBox` binding?

Comment: The short answers is no. Either you use the binding generated by Caliburn or you have to write out the whole binding expression as in your sample.

Comment: Distance doesn't have to be a number, it's a model of what you want to be in the view.  So don't make the property a Double, make it be the string you want in the view.

Comment: Failing that just bind everything manually - the only thing that gets bound by name convention is the default bindable prop or the action. One binding isn't too horrid to look at is it?

Answer (score 4):

There is no possible way of what you want to do. The simplest way is that you provide yourself.
The second way is to expose the string property in the ViewModel and preformat it in the getter.